# Window.open an image and show scaled

Tags: javascript, window

I'd like to do a window.open on a JPG and the height fill the browser height and the width scales accordingly.

I can't seem to get this to work. Ideas? Will I encounter browser issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<style>
html,body,img{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:100%;
}
</style>
```